# How can I send (request.post) pandas dataframe/json to my raspberry-pi webserver?

Tags: python, html, pandas, raspberry-pi, webserver

I'm looking for guides/videos, advice, and tips on how I can take the dataframe/json data from python and just deploy it on a simple table via html/php on my raspberry-pi which is running as a webserver on my local network. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to do this for hours.

Comment: Which framework are you using for the server?

Comment: I setup apache2 on the pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with apache but getting your dataframe to display as a webpage is very simple using the `df.to_html()` method.

```
with open("dataframe.html", "w+") as f:
    html = df.to_html()
    f.write(html)
```

Now if you open `dataframe.html` locally you'll see your dataframe in the browser.

How you deploy that is another story -- it looks like python needs to be enabled. [This link should get you started...](https://techexpert.tips/apache/apache-enable-python-cgi/)